# How I can use JConsole to change logging setting in Websphere?

Tags: websphere, jmx

How I can use JConsole to change logging setting in Websphere? 
I need set logging level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe JConsole is supported (it conflicts with the JMX server inside the product).  Instead, you could use AdminControl within a connected wsadmin session, and then you can use the appendTraceString method of the TraceService MBean.